# No SSH access through a DDNS server under CGNAT

Tags: ssh, ddns

After configuring a no-ip DDNS service (including DDNS setup and port forwarding in the router), the local server can be accessed, but the SSH key does not allow access, and the access by password fails as well. This is the log generated:

```
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to subdomain.sytes.net [34.199.8.144] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.13
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.13 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000002
debug1: Authenticating to subdomain.sytes.net:22 as 'user'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:<any_key>
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'subdomain.sytes.net' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:8
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
debug1: get_agent_identities: ssh_fetch_identitylist: agent contains no identities
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:<any_key>
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:<any_key>
debug1: send_pubkey_test: no mutual signature algorithm
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
user@subdomain.sytes.net: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
```

The server can be accessed by SSH from this computer through the local IP, its public key is stored in the `authorized_keys` file.

Have tried solutions like [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/343574), did not work.

Note: some data has been deleted (like subdomain, user and key).

Update: When using the public IP (port 9264 forwards to server's 22 ), it gets hanged there:

```
$ ssh -v -p 9264 user@public.IP
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to public.IP [public.IP] port 9264.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1                                                                                                                               
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1                                                                                                                                     
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1                                                                                                                                
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1                                                                                                                                  
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1                                                                                                                             
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss type -1                                                                                                                                        
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1                                                                                                                                   
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1                                                                                                                                         
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1                                                                                                                                    
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.1
```

Comment: are you trying to access the server from within the same LAN but using the public (WAN) address? i.e 34.199.8.144

Comment: Search on this site and Google for "Hairpin NAT".  This is likely required to get what you are trying to do working, and requires router support that is likely missing.  Effectively packets originating in your network won't be bounced through the wan interface and back to the LAN unless your router supports hairpin nat, meaning you are stuck running split DNS, using a hosts file, referring to the computer on the LAN by IP address or something similar.

Comment: Based on the logs it’s not finding your authentication key, and it’s not even attempting, to use password authentication.

Comment: Correct @JaromandaX, just tryning to check if the service will be available from an external IP. Actually, I've logged in another server that I own (outside the LAN) and the result has been the same.

Comment: @davidgo haven't found anything like that browsing the router's options. I know that the ISP has activated CGNAT, don't know if this might have something to do with it.

Comment: If your ISP uses CGNAT, then you won't be able to expose services or do port forwarding, and DDNS won't do anything meaningful because you don't have a consistent public IP address. Your only option to make your ssh service accessible from the Internet would be some sort of external tunnel provider.

Comment: @GordonDavisson is correct. If you are trying to get through CGN you are likely hitting someone elses ssh box so you cant log in.  You would need to either use iov6 (if your provider supports it), a vpn that gives you a uniue IP or build a tunnel of some sort (which could be built using a reverse ssh tunnel if you can connect from your bix to another one which is publicly accessable - google "ssh revererse tunnel")

Comment: @GordonDavisson after deactivating CGNAT from the ISP now the server can be reached from the outside, but not from the internal LAN/WLAN. From a local computer, SSH raises a "Connection timed out" message and the DDNS address takes to the router's web (the server is 192.168.1.1 and the router is 192.168.1.99) even if port forwarding is correct.

Comment: @nightcod3r That sounds like your router doesn't support hairpin NAT. It's not generally a feature you can enable, it's just a capability that some routers' firmware supports, and some routers' firmware doesn't.